# How to use BCS in Word for editing BLOBs

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, word

If I have an External Content type defined with a StreamAccessor that will end up referencing Word docx files stored in another system (reason for using BCS), what options do I have for updating the docx file? I'm aware of the ability to expose a BLOB using the stream accessor and WebParts to open up Word (assuming the BLOB is a Word docx), but do I have to use some custom VSTO solution or the BDC client runtime from Word in order to write back changes?

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like StreamAccessor is a read only process.

I'm not sure you could implement it in a custom BDC model and have word pick that up (the save method), you may need to look at VSTO, and leveraging a new method of saving back into the external system from the client.

VSTO does have a method that supports intercepting the "save" commands.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.saveeventhandler.aspx